# Never shutting down a computer (Alienware)

Tags: motherboard, shutdown

I read that it's not a problem to leave a computer on for very long.
Then I was told it can damage it.
I have an Alienware Aurora R4 (07JNH0 motherboard) and I was wondering if there is some risks leaving the computer on for extended period of time, especially regarding the capacitors. In fact a Dell employee told me I should shut down the computer by removing the power chords a whole night every 2 or 3 days, which is a completely different statement that what I've heard so far. If not doing this, it can damage the computer or mother board according to him. I'm cautious about it.

I prefer leaving the computer on at all times, so I could receive instant messages from various apps that could be important.
So what do you think is the best practice ?

Any advices ?
Thank you.

Comment: Flagging as too broad of a question, but it's also largely opinion based, which is off-topic for this SE.

Comment: I leave my computer on 24/7.  Computer are designed to be used.  They are not designed to be used "only" a certain amount per day.

Comment: It will not hurt anything if you leave your computer on. After some time, strange things will start to happen with programs though. It's hard telling what may happen, but it's just a buggy thing about Windows. So it's good to restart it once in a while.

Comment: I don't see how it could be opinion based since there is only one best way to do. The best practice is the one that does damage the least your system. This is not an opinion, there can't be 2 best practice at the same time. I need to know the best practice for my specific hardware. I can give details if necessary;

Comment: @DrZoo - If a system becomes unstable after awhile, that indicates a problem with the software running on the system, not Windows specifically.  I run my system 24/7 and I only reboot it to install updates to it, and between those times it runs exactly the same every single day..

Comment: @Chatai - Leaving your system on, does not damage your system, if keeping a computer on damaged it computers would have never become popular.  In my opionion, a question "seeking the best practice?" to do something is not a good fit for a Q&A website like Superuser.  You have already received several highly opionated responses through comments and as an answer, none of them are incorrect or correct, they are just opionions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most you have been told is true, but only to the extent that its applicable (except the assertion that you should completely unplug it for hours on a cycle; thats just daft).

For instance, Powering on hardware does cause a spike that can cause wear to components, and they may undergo wide swings in component temperature during and just after boot, which can damage some types of hardware. Components that move constantly (fans) are more likely to seize at start up than just die while running.

At the same time, a system without appropriate cooling, can overheat over time, once again damaging your hardware.  Since these systems are often unused and unattended for significant portions of the day, you may not notice if a fan goes out, until your system shuts down due to excessive CPU temperature.

The only time completely depriving a system of power is a good idea, is when it is having significant issues caused by old or partly faulty hardware. For instance if an old laptop won't post, I recommend to people that they completely deprive it of power for an hour to let the caps drain, and then try again.

So, so sum up, My recommendation is that you leave it on, but monitor the state of the hardware at the times you are using it, so you notice that a given fan is dying or that a process has run amok and is super-heating your CPU, or your voltages are all over the place due to a dying power-supply.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. My system has good cooling and I monitor it everyday having a program always launched for that purpose. So basically what Dell told me (I supposedly damaged my motherboard and some capacitors by leaving it on for too long for my specific hardware -they charged me a new $800 motherboard at the end of the discussion) is just wrong ?

Comment: definitely. Dell did ship faulty capacitors for years, in what I call the Internationals Capacitor Conspiracy: http://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/hardware/leaking-capacitors-muck-up-motherboards Dell got the bulk of them.

Comment: @Chatai Did they really charge you $800 on a new mobo? You can find quality, long lasting mobos on Newegg or Amazon for anywhere between $100-$300.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I asked for a lower price and they proposed me $670. I'm not even sure the mobo I have is damaged, I think not. I'll probably have to buy a compatible non-Dell mobo in the future when my mobo will finally die, as you suggest.